# Монитор Dell 2212h подключён к лептопу Acer, не могу настроить

Tags: windows-10, ноутбук, dell

Уважаемые пользователи,
подключил через VGA указанный монитор к ноутбуку Acer Aspire E1, Windows 10 Home.
Проблема: монитор тупо копирует настройки экрана ноутбука, это при том, что ноутбук видит, что монитор может поддерживать более крупный размер экрана.
Есть ли возможность решить проблему, или видеокарта не позволит?

Comment: Попробуйте скачать и поставить драйвер монитора с сайта Dell.

Comment: Попробуйте не дублировать экран а расширить его, тогда у монитора будет свое разрешение, а у ноутбука свое

Comment: Спасибо тем, кто откликнулся. Драйвер  сайта Dell не помог (оказалось, у меня стоял такой же). Зато помогло покопаться в настройках драйвера видеокарты от Intel.
Вот что мне непонятно: я баланс цветов настроил одинаковый на встроенном мониторе и на подключённом. Однако цвета на них выглядят совершенно по-разному...